# Why do we need contexClassLoader

Tags: java, contextclassloader

I'm wondering why Java introduced contexClassLoader for threads. I know that it is usualy used by frameworks and application servers which have to dynamically find and load classes.

However I don't understand why Java introduced contexClassLoader when we can achieve the same functionality simply by adding field that will hold necessary class loader.

```java
class ThreadWithCustomClassloader extends Thread
{
    ClassLoader threadClassLoader;

    public void run()
    {
       //use threadClassLoader to dynamically find and load classes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - having an instance variable for the class loader is exactly what the Thread class uses to implement this. What's different in your solution?

Do you mind about the setter? Setting the class loader is important to be able to reuse the same thread (e.g. in the servlet container) for a completely different environment (web application). Thread instances are considered expensive...

Comment: Yes, my solution provides the same functionality. I'm confused why Java introduced standard mechanism for changing threads class loader if it so simple to do it by your self.

Comment: I did not understand second part of your post - about setter.

Comment: Java provides a standard mechanism because its frequently used!

Comment: if really it is so frequently used, in my opinion it would be better to create new class that extends Thread which would provide necessary functionality.

Comment: SO, if you write a component that does not make any assumptions about its context, but wants to get its context class loader you always have to check (instanceof ThreadWithCustomClassloader) ? I dont' get the reasoning why the feature should *not* be in the base implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**The default class loader mechanism in JVM is parent delegation, Thread context classloaders provide a back door around the classloading delegation scheme.**
Take JNDI for instance: its guts are implemented by bootstrap classes in rt.jar (starting with J2SE 1.3), but these core JNDI classes may load JNDI providers implemented by independent vendors and potentially deployed in the application's -classpath. This scenario calls for a parent classloader (the primordial one in this case) to load a class visible to one of its child classloaders (the system one, for example). **Normal J2SE delegation does not work, and the workaround is to make the core JNDI classes use thread context loaders**, thus effectively "tunneling" through the classloader hierarchy in the direction opposite to the proper delegation.

For more information, please check [which class loader should you use](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077344/core-java/find-a-way-out-of-the-classloader-maze.html)